# Are these word adjectives or pronouns?

Tags: parts-of-speech

There is an exercise in my grammar book that asks to identify the type of pronoun in a sentence (personal, possessive, relative, demonstrative, indefinite, interrogative, reciprocal or reflexive).

In three of those sentences I feel the capitalised words are not pronouns but adjectives. Am I wrong, and why?

1) HER husband was late.
The answer is personal pronoun but I think it should be a possessive adjective.

2) WHICH one shall we go for?
The answer is interrogative pronoun but I think it should be interrogative adjective.

3) That’s MY house.
The answer is possessive pronoun but I think it’s possessive adjective.

Comment: Read this wiki article on [determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners)

Comment: @Looper Complicating things!

Comment: Here *her* is a pronoun, because *her* is taking the place of a noun (like *Alice's*). They're also adjectives, because they modify a noun. But it looks like *adjective* wasn't one of your choices.

Comment: How did your dictionaries define those words and what did that leave unclear, please?